# X needs to be a numerical value

Tags: r

I have an assignment for a statistics class where I copied code from the teacher, but I keep getting an error where x should be numerical and I don't see where the issue is

```
Survey=read.csv("ClassSurvey.csv", na.strings = c("",          " ",   "NA"))
attach(Survey)
library(FSAdata)                  

op = par(oma=c(0,0,1.5,0), mar=c(3,3,2,1))
hist(Height ~ Gender,
     las=1,
     nrow=2, ncol=1,
     cex.main=0.9, cex.lab=0.8, cex.axis=0.8, 
     mgp=c(1.8,0.6,0), 
     xlab = "Height (cms)")
```

thank you!!

Comment: Hi, Please check the path by ```getwd()``` if file is not there then set the path by ```setwd()``` then use ```read.csv()``` hope this will help

Comment: Could you specify what you want the code to do? A histogram of Height for each Gender? Your formula `Height ~ Gender` suggests that the x-axis should be Gender, but your `xlab` argument will be "Height", so something is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems. First, you can't make a histogram on a variable that is not numeric. Try this:

```
data(ToothGrowth)
str(ToothGrowth)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ len : num  4.2 11.5 7.3 5.8 6.4 10 11.2 11.2 5.2 7 ...
 $ supp: Factor w/ 2 levels "OJ","VC": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dose: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...

attach(ToothGrowth)
```

Attempt to draw a histogram of `supp`, a variable of class "factor" (it's not numeric).

```
> hist(supp)
Error in hist.default(supp ~ dose) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Your second problem is that the `hist` function doesn't accept a formula `y ~ x`. So

```
hist(len~supp)
```

fails as well, even though `len` **is** numeric. This works though:

```
hist(len)
```

I wonder if you copied the teacher's code incorrectly? Or the teacher's code is incorrect? Or something else.